# Null Pointer exception when running a jar but worls fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

addressStandardisationResponse.getStandardisedUKaddress().getAddressLine1()

addressStandardisationResponse : this is the response object i am getting after calling a service  which has the Standardised Uk address object filled . This works fine in my eclipse but when i exported it as runnable jar and running on another machine its giving null pointer exception at the same line

Comment: We will need to see more code. `addressStandardisationResponse` is a third party class, please include the method throwing the exception.

Comment: Imagine you are coming to this question with no context besides what you have given above. Would you be able to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: It may be something related to classpath item that is available via eclipse but not when you run via jar

Comment: also, are you calling the service with the same details or address? it might be a problem with the data for that request, and nothing to do with eclipse.